PyMongo query function with multiple args and passing results to Dash app
Ok, I have a MongoDB database, using a Python module to perform CRUD functions, and passing the resulting info into a Dash app.
Here is the relevant Python method:
   def read(self, query):
        results = self.database.animals.find(query)
        
        return results

and the callback function I need help with:
@app.callback(Output('datatable-id','data'),
              [Input('rescue-dropdown', 'value')],
             prevent_initial_call=True)
def update_dashboard(value):   
    #start case
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({}))
    # filter interactive data table with MongoDB queries
    if (value == 'Water Rescue'):
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({'animal_type': 'Dog'}))
        
       
    df.drop(columns=['_id'],inplace=True)
    data=df.to_dict('records')
       
       
    return (data)

All of this works as intended so far. The issue comes when I try to add more query filters as arguments in shelter.read(). How do I either amend the Python method to accept multiple arguments or change something in the callback function to allow for it?
For this dropdown value ('Water Rescue'), the query filters are:
{'animal_type': 'Dog'}, {'breed': {'$in':['Labrador Retriever Mix', 'Chesapeake Bay Retriever', 'Newfoundland']}}, {'sex_upon_outcome': 'Intact Female'}, {'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$gte': '26'}}, {'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$lte': '156'}}

I tried changing the query parameter in the Python method to **kwargs or *args, but either did it incorrectly or that's not the answer.
I can include more code if necessary but since there are no issues until I try to add more filters I assume this is where the problem occurs.

You need to specify all the conditions as a single argument, ie. instead of having one dictionary per condition, specify all of them in the same dictionary.
Also note that :

For most data types, comparison operators only perform
comparisons on documents where the BSON type of the target field matches the type of the query operand.

So if the 'age in weeks' fields are stored as integers in your database, you need to use integers for the $gte and $lte operands (cf. Type Bracketing) :
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(shelter.read({
    'animal_type': 'Dog',
    'breed': {
        '$in': [
            'Labrador Retriever Mix', 
            'Chesapeake Bay Retriever', 
            'Newfoundland'
        ]
    },
    'sex_upon_outcome': 'Intact Female',
    'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$gte': 26},
    'age_upon_outcome_in_weeks': {'$lte': 156}
}))


This allows the query to run without error but produces no results.

@ChelaineEchols Note the operator between all the conditions is $and by default. Have you tried to query your database directly (in SQL not, not via pyMongo) ? What is the actual SQL query and what are the results ?

Oh I could kiss you! Thank you so much for your help. I've been stuck on this assignment for so long. I really appreciate it!
P.S. the problem was just that the age in weeks needed to be integers not strings. Putting the query directly into mongosh allowed me to add in one filter at a time to see when the problem occured.

@ChelaineEchols Thanks for the feedback. I've improved the answer to reflect your comment and help other users to find the solution if they land in the same situation. Please consider upvoting/accepting if it sounds good to you.
